# Storing values of second <td>'s as comma separated just before deletion

Tags: jquery, html-table, delete-row

I have a table having 2 `<td>`'s one is having a checkbox and other having a value:

My table as follows:

```
<table border="1" id="table_sundry">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_1"></td>
             <td id="val1">a</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_2"></td>
             <td id="val2">b</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_3"></td>
             <td id="val3">c</td>
    </tr>
                  <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_4"></td>
             <td id="val4">d</td>
    </tr>
                        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_5"></td>
             <td id="val3">e</td>
    </tr>
</table>
                      <input type="button" id="btn_del" value="deleterow">
```

I have a button to delete the rows after checking that particular row.

In delete What I doing is as follows:

```
$("#btn_del").click(function(){ 
   var checked = $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").size();
    var total = $("#table_sundry tr").size()-1; 
    var rowcnt =  document.getElementById("table_sundry").rows.length-1;  

    var flag = 0;
    if($("#chk_"+rowcnt).prop('checked') == true){ //if delete contains last row
        $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").parents('tr').remove();

         flag =1;
        //updateRowCount(flag);
    }
    else{ 
            $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").parents('tr').remove();
            //updateRowCount(flag);
        }
});
```

**I need to store the values of second column as comma separated. 
Suppose if I delete first and last column I should get `a,e` in the variable.**

Refer fiddle : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u8p5eovb/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ft6qtja/2/

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="table_sundry">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_1"></td>
             <td id="val1">a</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_2"></td>
             <td id="val2">b</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_3"></td>
             <td id="val3">c</td>
    </tr>
                  <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_4"></td>
             <td id="val4">d</td>
    </tr>
                        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_5"></td>
             <td id="val3">e</td>
    </tr>
</table>
                      <input type="button" id="btn_del" value="deleterow">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var values = [];
var csv = ""; // Store Comma separated values in this variable;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn_del").click(function(){ 

    var checkboxes = $("#table_sundry tr input:checked");

    if (checkboxes.length > 0) { 

      $.each(checkboxes, function (index, checkbox) {

        var tr = $(checkbox).closest("tr");

        var value = tr.find("td:eq(1)").html();

        values.push(value);

        csv = values.join();

        tr.remove();

      });

      alert(csv);

    }
    else {

      alert("Please select an item.");

    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

By making small changes you will achieve this

```
<table border="1" id="table_sundry">
    <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value='a' id="chk_1"></td>
         <td id="val1">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value='b' id="chk_2"></td>
         <td id="val2">b</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value='c' id="chk_3"></td>
         <td id="val3">c</td>
    </tr>
              <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value='d' id="chk_4"></td>
         <td id="val4">d</td>
</tr>
                    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value='e' id="chk_5"></td>
         <td id="val3">e</td>
</tr>
```

and jquery like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn_del").click(function(){ 
        var checked = $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").size();
        var total = $("#table_sundry tr").size()-1; 
        var values="";
        var rowcnt =  document.getElementById("table_sundry").rows.length-1;  

        var flag = 0;
        if($("#chk_"+rowcnt).prop('checked') == true){ //if delete contains last row
           console.log("ëe"+ $("#chk_"+rowcnt).prop('value'));
            $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").parents('tr').remove();

             flag =1;
            //updateRowCount(flag);
        }
        else{
            var vals=$("#table_sundry tr input:checked");
            for(var i=0;i<vals.length;i++){

                if(i>0)
                    values+=",";
                values+=vals[i].value;
            }
            console.log(values);
                $("#table_sundry tr input:checked").parents('tr').remove();
                //updateRowCount(flag);
            }
    });
});
```

In values variable containe comma seperated values

Comment: It is giving first item only!!

Comment: Check the Solution by @Ahsan

Answer (score 0):

we can also solve it using this

```
 var value=[];
               var allValue;
               $('#btn_del').click(function (){
                   $("table tr :checkbox:checked").each(function (){
                     var attrValue=$(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").attr('id') ;
                     console.log('value is'+attrValue);
                     value.push($('#'+attrValue).html());
                     allValue=value.join();
                     alert('Values Are'+allValue);
                     if($(this).closest('tr').length>0){
                         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                     }

                  });
```